# java command works in command prompt but not in powershell

Tags: java, windows, powershell, environment-variables, system-variable

I have following problem. I installed new OpenJDK 17:

`c:\java\jdk-17.0.2`

I've set up JAVA_HOME to it and added to path:

`JAVA_HOME\bin`

in cmd when I type java -version it works.
But when I run it from VS code or powershell it says following:

`Error: could not open C:\java\jdk-17.0.2\lib\jvm.cfg'`

Has anybody faced similar issue?

Thanks,
M.

**UPDATE #1:**

here are my env variable settings:
[image: env vars]

path:

[image: path]

and still not working:
PS
[image: powershell]

Answer (score 0):

Here are 5 steps you can follow to fix the issue:

1. In the run dialog box, enter `sysdm.cpl`
2. In the window that came up, navigate to Advanced tab.
3. Click on the Environment Variables button.
4. Add the location of your java installation (the bin directory) to the PATH variable.

```
;%ProgramFiles%/Java/jre%version%/bin
```

followed by a semi-colon `;`

5. Do the following and check again with a new PowerShell prompt

   5.1. Add a `JAVA_HOME` variable equal to something like: `C:\Java\JDK-17.0.2`

   5.2. Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the beginning of your
   PATH variable.

Comment: still not working :(